# How to include and center a wide html content in the page?

Tags: html, css

I am dynamically including an html content in the page.
The content is a tree structure in html which is usually huge in height and width.
I want that after inclusion with AJAX the root node of the tree is visible : the included HTML content is centered.

**UPDATE1**: in the MWE I just use width:2000px to imitate something wider than the screen page. Point is that to center this huge thing on the page not to change its width (Scaling could be acceptable but how?).

**UPDATE2**: The root of the included tree should be horizontally centered but its other parts also needs to be available through scroll bars of the browser or some inner scroll bars.

What are the simple and correct ways of doing it (without frames as they are deprecated) by **styling**?

**UPDATE3**: Below the screenshot of a real example. After tree is generated and included dynamically in the bottom of the page, it is not visible for a client.
One needs to use scrollbars to see the root of a tree.

**UPDATE4**: See the one possible option where the included content is placed in a window with scrollbars which needs to be zoomable, via browser or vis additional functionality.

[image]

[image]

**MWE :** https://jsfiddle.net/kowalsky/tgkbn8wp/2/

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <h1>Test page</h1>
    <div>
        So here comes a long text that might fill the page and wrap outomatically like this. 
        Below is a WIDETHING which is supposed to content an HTML loaded dynamically via AJAX.
        The loaded content is usually wider and is impossible to fit to the page.
        <b>What are the ways to put WIDETHING centered on the page, i.e. CENTER is in the center of the page?</b>
    </div>

    <div class="frame">
        <div class="wideThing">
            CENTER
            <div class="box">BOX1</div>
            <span class="box">BOX2</span>
            <span class="box">BOX3</span>
            <span class="box">BOX4</span>
            <div class="box">BOX5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS :**

```css
.wideThing {
    width: 2000px; 
    text-align: center;
}

.frame {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.box {
    padding: 40px 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question, dont you want to set your `.wideThing` width to `width: 100%; `

Comment: Then the included wide content will run out of the page and won't be centered anyway. So, that's not a solution for a wide content.

Comment: Is it ok to use jQuery?!

Comment: @5aledmaged  It is ok to use jQuery, but the tree is generated later dynamically after a page is loaded. So, how I will make jQuery modify the layout of the included tree?
It is also possible to modify an empty element, where the tree is loaded later.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
.wideThing {
    position: relative;
    width: 2000px; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

That first moves the left border  to the middle and than moves it back left by 50% of its own width, thereby centering it horizontally.

https://jsfiddle.net/p7d2j323/1/

Comment: This means that the left part of the tree (in this case a part of a box) is hidden for a client. Is that the case? I want that the included tree will be possible to see, e.g., using scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```
.wideThing{
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tgkbn8wp/4/

Comment: .wideThing is just a class to imitate something wide for MWE. Putting the real tree example there would make the MEW complicated.
So changing .wideThing is not a solution, but to place it with its center in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `jQuery` to set the position of the horizontal scrollbar at the center of the tree.

This could be accomplished using the `.scrollLeft()` method and some calculations to get the new position of the horizontal scrollbar.

But bear in mind that you'd have to execute this `script` after the tree had finished loading.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgkbn8wp/7/).

And of course you could set the position of the vertical scroll bar similarly using `.scrollTop()`.

More about [`.scrollLeft()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) and [`.scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) on jQuery's website.